# Configure enzyme-to-json with Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I'm trying to test my react components with jest and Enzyme.

When I import enzyme-to-json in the particular test case it works. But instead of doing it manually I would like to configure jest to do it.

I already tryed adding "snapshotSerializers": ["enzyme-to-json/serializer"]
to my jest config but it doesn't seem to be working.

How do I configure jest to use enzyme-to-json on my wrappers?

### This code works

**Header.test.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { shallow } from 'enzyme'
import toJSON from 'enzyme-to-json'
import Header from '../../components/Header'

test('Should render Header correctly', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Header />)
    expect(toJSON(wrapper)).toMatchSnapshot()
})
```

### I want Jest to automatically use enzyme-to-json in all my wrappers so that this code works aswell:

**Header.test.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { shallow } from 'enzyme'
import Header from '../../components/Header'

test('Should render Header correctly', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Header />)
    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot()
})
```

**jest.config.json**

```
{
    "setupFiles": [
        "raf/polyfill",
        "<rootDir>/src/tests/setupTests.js",
    ],
    "snapshotSerializers": ["enzyme-to-json/serializer"]
}
```

**Test script**

"test": "jest --config=jest.config.json"

### **expected**

```
exports[`Should render Header correctly 1`] = `
<header>
  <h1>
    Title
  </h1>
  <NavLink
    activeClassName="is-active"
    exact={true}
    to="/"
  >
    Home
  </NavLink>
  <NavLink
    activeClassName="is-active"
    to="/create"
  >
    Create
  </NavLink>
</header>
`;
```

### **result**

```
exports[`Should render Header correctly 1`] = `ShallowWrapper {}`;
```

Comment: Hmm...that's how you add it to `jest.config.json`.  I just added it to a project using `Jest` v24.5 and it worked fine...

Comment: I was having a similar issue and what fixed it for me was: _stopping and restarting the jest suite in watch mode_. Changing the `jest.config.json` caused my test suite to re-run so I was under the impression that the new config was picked up but clearly it wasn't. This might be a no-brainer to most but I thought I'd throw it out there.

Comment: Thanks @k427h1c I fix this problem by restart yarn test instead of keep it running after change jest config.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was an extra "," on my jest config file but somehow the console was not able to detect the error.

```
jest.config.json

{
    "setupFiles": [
        "raf/polyfill",
        "<rootDir>/src/tests/setupTests.js", <------- this comma
    ],
    "snapshotSerializers": ["enzyme-to-json/serializer"]
}
```

Remove the comma to fix

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue. Funny thing is, I copied your file and my `setupTests` is at the root of the `src` folder and Jest still ran happy (no Adapter complaints!).

For now I'm just using the import.

Answer (score 0):

I had problem with jest config. Following entry was just ignored:

```
"snapshotSerializers": ["enzyme-to-json/serializer"]
```

So I found manual replacement of that config. In the file setupTests add following:

```
import serializer from "enzyme-to-json/serializer";
expect.addSnapshotSerializer(serializer);
```

file setupTests can be added to the config (if not auto-defined as in CRA) like following:

```
setupFilesAfterEnv: ["<rootDir>/src/setupTests.js"]
```